# How to add a tabbed menu on group main page (panel)?

Tags: navigation, panels, organic-groups

I managed to get panels working with og 7.x-2.1 following:
- http://modulesunraveled.com/organic-groups/part-3-organic-groups-layout
- http://www.initsix.co.uk/organic-groups-panels-and-views-drupal-7

Now I'd like to add a tabbed menu on the "main og content", where I mainly divide by content-type (documents, agenda, forum, news..).

I tried to follow http://www.austinprogressivecalendar.com/blog/creating-drupal-panels-tabs in order to create tabs, where each tab is a panel.
However I don't know how to eventually add what would be my (sub) panel to the main content of the group page, and more in general I wander if there is a less cumber stone way to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

I got a working and straight solution (tabs are panel style) using panels_tabs.

panels_ajax_tab seems more nice (and more clean from a designer point-of-view), but it is also more cumbersome as it only accepts mini-panels as tab elements, and then I'm not sure how to pass the group information down from the main panel to the mini-panel and finally the embedded view panel.

Further panels_tab load all the page at once and then just hide the unused tabs, so if too many views are loaded the page can take pretty much long time to load !